# FCM push notification data export to linked BigQuery not working

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, google-bigquery, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've recently linked my Firebase project to a BigQuery as indicated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#bigquery-data-export), and also installed the FCM SDK version 20.1.0 as indicated [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#enable-message-delivery-data-export-on-android), but even after enabling the data export by calling `setDeliveryMetricsExportToBigQuery(true)` in a local app build, and sending some push notifications via production to capture some push metrics, nothing was exported to the `firebase_messaging` dataset, nor a single table was created by the integration. I've activated only the Cloud Messaging data export for this project on all app variants (debug, test, beta, production).

I've tried receiving and interacting with push notification on both emulated and physical devices, and even after waiting more than 24h I was unable to find the push notification delivery metrics in the database.

Running the following query against the created dataset after the integration link, I get no results back:

```sql
select * from firebase_messaging.data limit 100
```

Error message: `Not found: Table *****:firebase_messaging.data was not found in location US` (I've hidden the project id).

When looking at the `Firebase Messaging Export` job history of this same BigQuery, I find the following line within every daily run: `Source data not found for 'data$20200215'`.

With that said, I have a few questions around what could be causing this:

1. Is there anything else that needs to be done that may not be present in these documentation links I've shared?
2. Is a local build a possible cause for this unexpected behavior, even by setting the production variant for it?
3. Can the data export feature be affected by using the sandbox version of the BigQuery?
4. I noticed is that the BigQuery uses US region and my app is distributed to the Brazil market, could this influence the push metrification?

Comment: Hi, I am from IOS background. Past few weeks I am also not able to get data in bigquery. Referring https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery, It mentioned that ‘Important: An analytics label is required to display all types of statistics for data messages.’

Comment: Have you take a look for this document https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/bigquery-export ?

Comment: Hi @vinay and muscat, I'm already using the analytics label myself, and yet no data was exported to the BigQuery. I also followed all the steps to link the sandbox version of BigQuery to my firebase project based on these documentations:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/bigquery-export
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery

Comment: @Jefferson Thanks for the reply. Please update if you got solution

Comment: After some study, data is exported to BigQuery for me. I have implemented all the methods of FIRMessagingDelegate and UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate. Hope it will be useful to iOS developers. For more info, https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in